# How to create env-file in centos 7 for docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to host an application in docker. I am following a guide to host that application in docker, in that its mentioned use the 'env-file' in this way and given all the parameters to include in the env-file.

My question is , how do I edit the env-file in centos ? where will this be located in??

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the variables in a `.sh` file inside `/etc/profile.d/` or in `~/.bash_profile` would do the trick. Keep in mind that if you intend to use these environment variables in a service script, it might not work as you expect since service purges all environment variables except a few.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44378/148497.